# A good introductory paper for STDP as a model for Spiking Neural Networks?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, neural-networks

I've been browsing google and various online databases, but I was unable to find any generic Spike-Time-Dependent Plasticity models that haven't been optimised or tweaked. Was just wondering if any of you had a good introductory paper, as there are plenty on Hebbian Learning but not STDP which can be used in Neural Networks.